# PHP print- TD class is not working

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following problem: 
I want to print a `<td>` in PHP, which will have the class "myclass" which gives blue background to the `<td>` that cointains variables less than 5 ,and an orange background to the `<td>` that contains variables greater than 5 .
Problem is that when ever i try to do that, the `<td>` background stays default.
Anyone knows why?

```
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.myclass{

background-color:orange;

}
</style>
<style type="text/css">
.myclass2{
background-color:red;
}

</style>

<table id="myTable"></table>
<?php
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
$myVar=rand(0,10);
  if($myVar<5){
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td class='myclass'>$myVar</td>";
    print "<br>";
    print "</tr>";
  }
   else{
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td class='myclass2'>$myVar</td>";
    print "<br>";
    print "</tr>";


}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you closed your `<table>` tag to early:

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

This should be in this format:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Example with your code:**

```
<table id="myTable">
<?php
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++){
$myVar=rand(0,10);
  if($myVar<5){
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td class='myclass'>$myVar</td>";
    print "<br>";
    print "</tr>";
  }
   else{
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td class='myclass2'>$myVar</td>";
    print "<br>";
    print "</tr>";
}
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: @DimitrisHD: glad to help you friend, if its work dont forgot to accept this will help to others.